# Solving a system of ODEs with constant matrix and constant inhomogeneity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following system of ODEs using the method of undetermined coefficients.
$$\textbf{x}'(t)=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\4&2\end{bmatrix}\textbf{x}+\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
Notice that $4$ and $0$ are eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\4&2\end{bmatrix}.$ I have tried guessing that $\textbf{x}(t)=(\textbf{a}t+\textbf{b})e^{0t}.$ This gives us that $\textbf{a}=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\4&2\end{bmatrix}\textbf{a}t+\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\4&2\end{bmatrix}\textbf{b}+\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\end{bmatrix}.$ We need $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\4&2\end{bmatrix}\textbf{a}=0,$ which means that $\textbf{a}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix}.$ Then we need $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\4&2\end{bmatrix}\textbf{b}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix}$ but this has no solutions. Does anyone have a suggestion for a better guess?

Edit:
I made an error. For $\textbf{b},$ we actually needed to solve
$$\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\4&2\end{bmatrix}\textbf{b}=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Can you provide that system of ODEs? How does it look?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\4&2\end{bmatrix}\textbf{b}=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-2\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}2b_1+b_2\\4b_1+2b_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-2\end{bmatrix}$$
This gives you:
$$b_2=-1-2b_1$$
$$\implies b=b_1 \pmatrix { 1 \\-2}+\pmatrix {0 \\-1}$$
The first term is absorbed by the solution to the homogeneous DE so that you are left with:
$$x_p= \pmatrix { 1 \\-2}t+\pmatrix {0\\-1}$$